# Conditional Sum, Data in Two Sheets, Calculation in 3rd Sheet with Conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am preparing a sheet for Stock Inventory.
Sheet1 contains the Purchase Details
In Sheet 1, Column A contains the Batch no. of Product and Column B contains the Quantity we purchased.

In Sheet 2, Column A contains the Batch no. of Product and Column B contains the Quantity we Sold.

In Sheet 3, I am trying to make a stock details sheet.

So, that If we put Batch no. in Column A, Column B automatic gives the current Stock.

Suppose on 1st Jan, we purchased 1000 Quantity of Batch 1 (Sheet 1)

on 2nd Jan, We sold 300 Quantity of Batch 1 (Sheet2)
on 3rd Jan, We sold 200 Quantity of Batch 1 (Sheet2)

Sheet 3, Column B should give a correct figure of 500 Quantity left.

Is it possible ? I tried to do it through Sumif, If, Sumifs, but couldn't got success.

Plz help.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: What was the problem with the `SUMIFS`? This formula should work: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2)-SUMIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A:$A,$A2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will do what you need:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2)-SUMIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A:$A,$A2)
```